# Subdomain with www SSL binding error: No certificates when trying to add SSL Bindings for Azure Web App

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to add SSL binding to a sub domain. I have a wild card certificate in my Azure account.
[image]

There is no problem for me to bind to sub domain such as subdomain.domain.com, but it kept throwing the "No certificates when trying to add SSL Bindings for Azure Web App" error when I try to add www to the subdomain (in the picture above, [www.subdomain.domain.com](http://www.subdomain.domain.com))

[image]

I have read other posts regarding this issue, but no one mentioned anything about adding www. to the sub domain. I used to be able to do it with other sub domains in Azure without any problems, this might be related to Godaddy (my domain name provider) DNS settings, but I checked everything in Godaddy, the [www.subdomain.domain.com](http://www.subdomain.domain.com) link doesn't works unless I add [www.subdomain.domain.name](http://www.subdomain.domain.name) to the Azure app customer domain list. The link works, but it's http instead of https.

Comment: I find this happens when I first open that binding configuration sidebar. If I close and reopen it, suddenly it finds the certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after talking to 3 different support people at Microsoft, I finally got it working by going to the certificate TLS/SSL settings, click "Private Key Certificates", click "Create App Service Managed Certificate", then add [www.subdomain.domain.com](http://www.subdomain.domain.com) to the private key certificates list.
[image]